# Spelling rule for drug compounds' names: 'n' or an 'ne' at the ending

Tags: orthography

Does anybody know if there are any rules to guide whether to spell a drug compound's name with a simple 'n' or an 'ne' at the ending? E.g. sumatriptan, indomethacin, naproxen, aspirin vs. adrenaline, ergotamine, domperidone...

Comment: No, there aren't, because (most of them) are just names chosen by pharmaceutical companies.

Comment: Yes, there are.  Although they are conventions rather than rules.  The ending indicates the type of drug and is recognisable by pharmacists.

Comment: Sure, but I specifically mean the 'n' or an 'ne' at the ending as shown in the examples...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a convention in the pharmaceutical industry regarding the naming of drugs.

A guide to this is [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=YcFWCAAAQBAJ&pg=PP1&lpg=PP1&dq=drug+names+-in&source=bl&ots=bsI_H5gWx6&sig=_GZBw6RulZO6siroc8yT4rz4RQI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjV-aal27zRAhXiAJoKHRCOAvsQ6AEIPjAK#v=onepage&q=drug%20names%20-in&f=false) in Google books.

This is similar to the convention in Chemistry whereby the ending of a chemical name indicates the class of chemical to which it belongs.

However, this is a convention not a rule.  Not all drugs are named this way and there may be differences between generic names and trade names.

In your specific question *-in, -ine, -on* and *-one* indicate different drug types.

In any case, drug names are proper nouns, and therefore don't necessarily follow any English grammatical conventions.